# i am trying to develop signup with twitter task

Tags: twitter, authentication

by using servlet and jsp I am getting the twitter id,screen name but after authentication always redirecting to home page.please tell me how can i redirect to specific page 
example: my home page is:  localhost:8080/testtwitter/
redirecting page is     :  localhost:8080/testtwitter/getdata.jsp

but after authentication site redirect to home page.